# How to capture the image in picturebox and make it downloadable in c# application?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2008

im developing a c# application (Photo Album Viewer), Im having Picturebox (Displays the selected image in List ) and listbox (Lists the images available ibn database table ).
I can upload and store the images easily.
Now i want to download the image i.e. selected in the listbox
is there any standard procedure to capture the image in picture box and download the selected image?

Comment: Where are you uploading to and downloading from?

Comment: uploading to SQL Server Database and wants to retrieve it

Comment: If you've already set the `.Image` (or `.BackgoundImage`) to the desired one from the database, just save that out as a `Bitmap`.  Is that what you are after?

Comment: No.. 
im displaying the image (in PictureBox ) that is selected in the ListBox( This Listbox lists the all images in the database table.. Now i want to capture the image in picture box and to download to local machine using "saveasdialog" control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this (this is barebones, and would need a lot more error checking, etc.).  Make a button to save the image (or however you are going to handle that aspect of it).

```
    private void SaveMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.Filter = "JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";//change for your needs
        if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName);
        }
    }
```